# topic.bootstrap.servers properties while setting up snowflake sink connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to setup confluent snowflake sink connector and in that confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers is defined with all the broker:port
my question is, can we configure connector in a way where
a) Either we replace all broker hosts with the broker Load balancer URL?
b) If that's not possible then which other property or configuration I can do to setup the connector with broker load balancer URL in bootstrap configuration.

I tried replacing the broker:port with broker LB URL but on validation the data is not coming to the destination snowflake datasource/tables.

Answer (score 0):

It might not work in the reason that a load balancer URL might not be parsed correctly by the connector. The `confluent.topic.bootsrap.servers` property expects a list of individuals brokers in the format `host:port`.

As an alternative approach, you may try:

1. DNS resolution: Configuring your DNS server to resolve the load balancer hostname to individual broker hostnames and ports. In such a way, the connector can discover the brokers through DNS resolution.  Then, updating the `confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers` property with a comma-separated list of broker hostnames and ports instead of the load balancer URL.
2. Service Discovery: If you are using Discovery mechanisms like [Zookeeper](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-zookeeper/2.1.0.RC2/multi/multi_spring-cloud-zookeeper-discovery.html), you can leverage that for the broker discovery.

Attaching here as well a documentation as reference for using [Snowflake Sink Connector for Confluent Cloud.](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-snowflake-sink.html)